# Redis: How to get points in a given rectangle using geohash API?

Tags: redis, gis

example: Given 3 points `(1,1),(2,2),(5,5)` and a rectangle `(0,0)(3,3)`, get 2 points `(1,1)` and `(2,2)`.

It's easy to get points in a circle using `georadius`, but it seems that there is not a convenient way to get points in a rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to do that.

However, you can do a spatial search with a circle that can cover the whole rectangle. For each retrieved point, check if it's inside the rectangle.

Comment: As for_stack said. But, check this Lua script for some ideas including rectangle search (although w/o proper projection) https://github.com/RedisLabs/geo.lua, and if you're up to it, why not develop a Redis module that does what you need? ;)

Comment: @ItamarHaber I promise I'm not following you around the internet :) What do you mean by "proper projection"?

Comment: @MichaelKolber you can follow me wherever - I'm highly available :) I forgot the details, but there's more to translating a rect's coordinates than what I did in that script. I mean, it works, but probably doesn't provide accurate results.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question while exploring redis geospatial capabilities.

You can use the [GEOSEARCH](https://redis.io/commands/geosearch/) command to search points within a bounding box.

And I also found a well-written [article](https://www.memurai.com/blog/geospatial-queries-in-redis) explaining how to load a custom lua script to query points within a polygon.