# Does Redis geo have the capability for storing polygon?

Tags: redis, geospatial, geo, point-in-polygon

I followed several example about geospatial support in Redis. I tried to add POINT features to my Redis dataset without any problem, and subsequently I can query POINT names within certain radius (in meters, km, miles) of a certain coordinate (or a certain member of POINT).

The next immediate feature i need to try is POINT-in-POLYGON query. Now I am curious :

Does Redis geo have the capability for storing polygon?
If yes, does this polygon capability come as native or need another stack of software/extension?

Comment: No built-in way to do that. A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44019693/redis-how-to-get-points-in-a-given-rectangle-using-geohash-api).

Comment: That would actually be a great addition to redis :)

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Interesting. I am looking or this as well. The closest I find is https://github.com/RedisLabs/geo.lua

Comment: @grabhints  My motive was to get to know Redis for the first time, without specific urge to use it, as I am happy with PostGIS. So after that point, knowing that there's no built-in way for Point-in-arbitrary-polygon query, I did not dig more. Not to mention that, as i recall, the available plugin (i believe, the one in Github) has some degree of inacurracy. Nevertheless I am curious too with this Point-in-arbitrary-polygon query too. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is still not possible to store polygons with redis geospatial.

But I found an [article](https://www.memurai.com/blog/geospatial-queries-in-redis) explaining how to load a custom lua script to query points (stored in redis) within a polygon. The [GEOSEARCH](https://redis.io/commands/geosearch/) command allows you to do that for a bounding box out of the box if it is enough for you.